# Undefined array after push

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I'm trying to obtain to sort an array of mountain from the tallest to the smallest but when trying to print, I get

```
TypeError: mountainArray[i] is undefined
```

I think i'm not missing any step for the solution but I get undefined.

Thanks in advance

Code below:

```js
var position;
var height;

function Mountain(position, height) {
  this.position = position;
  this.height = height;
}

function sortMountain(a, b) {
  return b.height - a.height;
}

var mountainArray = [];

// game loop
while (true) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var mountainH = parseInt(readline()); // represents the height of one mountain, from 9 to 0.

    mountainArray.push(Mountain(i, mountainH));
    mountainArray.sort(sortMountain);


  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    print(mountainArray[i].position);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have your class written:

```
function Mountain(position, height) {
  this.position = position;
  this.height = height;
}
```

You need to use the `new` keyword when you push:

```
while (true) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var mountainH = parseInt(readline()); // represents the height of one mountain, from 9 to 0.

    mountainArray.push(new Mountain(i, mountainH)); // HERE
    mountainArray.sort(sortMountain);


  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    print(mountainArray[i].position);
  }
}
```

as pointed out in the comments, you should only sort once, no need to do it every time in your loop.

Comment: the readline is called before. the issue was missing the new part from  mountainArray.push(new Mountain(i, mountainH)); seems I need to learn JS from the scratch

Comment: Also should only sort array once...not each iteration of loop

Comment: Note that while the code correctly fixes the error, the text is a little off.  `new` has nothing to do with `push`ing.  You need `new` because you have a plain constructor function in `Mountain`, which doesn't return anything if you don't use it with `new`.  You could use `push` without `new` if you chose to write `Mountain` in a different manner.

Comment: ^^^ I put that in there, right before your comment. thanks

Comment: Sure enough.  It might be good to note that there are those who find `new` (and `this`) horrible features of JS.  I'm not one of them, but I do sympathise.